# meteorjs creating a patch for existing package/project

Tags: shell, meteor

I have a MeteorJS project and have created a packing script to build all the dependencies and deploy, which works fine.

I wanted to know if there is a command to create a patch. The idea is when I add new files and features, I would like to create a patch and only build and deploy only those files.

My package script looks something like:

```
echo "Check if output folder exists"
if [ ! -d "output" ]; then
  mkdir output
fi

echo "Building the project"
meteor build output/ --directory

echo "Changing directory"
cd output/bundle/programs/server

echo "Installing all Node dependencies"
nmp install

cd ../../../

echo "Compressing the package"
zip -r bundle.zip bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `rsync` could help you. It's a command line tool which syncs only differences between source and destination. Works with files and folders.

You could use this line of code:

```
rsync -arv output/bundle/ username@$myhost.com:/home/username/myapp/bundle/
```

This command will upload differences from your local `bundle` folder to the remote `bundle`.

More info on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

Comment: thanks for the response, its not going to be possible for me to use rsync; the reason being I can only deploy zip files over and unzip them accordingly, so the worst case would be to create a local instance of the old package, do rsync and then zip them to deploy it.

Comment: As far as I know, you can use rsync for zipped files. I use rsync for deploying my Meteor applications bundles (tar.gz).